# Worklight v6.0 Location Service issue : WIFI policy should include accessPointFilters specification

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-geolocation

according to IBM Infocenter documentation, i've setup the following policy for WIFI location service:

```
function loadWifiLocation() {
  var policy = {
          Geo: {
              timeout: 3000,
              enableHighAccuracy: true
          },
          Wifi: {
              interval: 3000,
              signalStrengthThreshold: 15,
              accessPointFilters: [{SSID:"MYWIFI"}]
          }
  };
  WL.Device.Wifi.acquireVisibleAccessPoints(loadWifiLocationSuccess, loadWifiLocationFailure, policy);
}
```

Unfortunately, running on Android, the following error is thrown:

```
08-23 15:37:18.910: E/Web Console(17385): Uncaught Error: WIFI policy should include accessPointFilters specification at file:///data/data/com.InfoCenter/files/www/default/wlclient/js/deviceSensors/wifi.js:43
```

In the wifi.js file, the following line check the accessPointFilters attribute of policy:

```
if (policy.accessPointFilters == undefined)
```

But, in the Infocenter documentation, the accessPointFilters is not attribute of policy, but of policy.Wifi....
Either the documentation is wrong or the javascript libs code is bugged!

Anyway, i can't get it work (even with fixing the policy.accessPointFilters issue).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling acquireVisibleAccessPoints it expects only the Wifi part of the policy. For your code, could you please try passing in policy.Wifi as the third parameter instead of policy?

Comment: all right, the Infocenter documentation is confusing... "The policy object has the same properties as the WiFi portion of the object defined in the WL.Device.startAcquisition function. "